# How to customize DRF reset password link?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**What I want to achieve**

Backend is DRF. The front end is React.js. I'm making an app and implementing Reset password. When user resets password, email will be sent to the user's email.

**Premise**

I am currently using the following libraries

https://github.com/anexia-it/django-rest-passwordreset/blob/master/README.md

When user resets password, he got the link below.

http://localhost:8000/api/password_reset/confirm/?token=604c13ce7bff445

However I would like to customize this link.

I use React.js so I want to make like.

http://localhost:3002/api/password_reset/confirm/?token=604c13ce7bff445

Is that possible? If so, how?

**Models.py**

```
@receiver(reset_password_token_created)
def password_reset_token_created(sender, instance, reset_password_token, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Handles password reset tokens
    When a token is created, an e-mail needs to be sent to the user
    :param sender: View Class that sent the signal
    :param instance: View Instance that sent the signal
    :param reset_password_token: Token Model Object
    :param args:
    :param kwargs:
    :return:
    """
    # send an e-mail to the user
    context = {
        'current_user': reset_password_token.user,
        'username': reset_password_token.user.username,
        'email': reset_password_token.user.email,
        'reset_password_url': "{}?token={}".format(
            instance.request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('password_reset:reset-password-confirm')),
            reset_password_token.key)
    }

    # render email text
    email_html_message = render_to_string('email/user_reset_password.html', context)
    email_plaintext_message = render_to_string('email/user_reset_password.txt', context)

    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        # title:
        "Password Reset for {title}".format(title="Some website title"),
        # message:
        email_plaintext_message,
        # from:
        "noreply@somehost.local",
        # to:
        [reset_password_token.user.email]
    )
    msg.attach_alternative(email_html_message, "text/html")
    msg.send()
```

**/Desktop/my_app/my_project/accounts/templates/email/user_reset_password.html**

```
{% block subject %}
【MY App】Password Reset
{% endblock subject %}

{% block text_body %}
Dear {{ current_user }}.

Thank you for using My App.
A password reset request has been made.

Please reset your password from the link below.
{{ reset_password_url }}

--------------------------------------
Publisher: My App
--------------------------------------

{% endblock text_body %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this reference you should be able to customize your link.
[Password Reset in Django Rest Framework](https://medium.com/@incrediblechamp1/password-reset-in-django-rest-framework-9b8a6a623179)

Answer (score 0):

The following code works

```
context = {
    'current_user': reset_password_token.user,
    'username': reset_password_token.user.username,
    'email': reset_password_token.user.email,
    'reset_password_url': "put_your_website_url/password_reset_confirm/?token=" + reset_password_token.key
}
```